# Best practice JS API (json) data usage, "models" or JSON - Performance, maintainability, resources

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, es6-class

I building an application with Laravel and VueJS (and Vuex). I'm not very experienced in building applications with these framworks or front-ends. I wonder what's the best practice or best way to use the data i receive from the API in the front-end.

My application has e.g. accounts which contains 1 or more users. The front end shows e.g. an overview with all accounts and also a list with all users (e.g. admin purposes). My API returns something like this (example):

**Some context to explain my question:**

```
// When fetch account(s)
data: {
  account: {
    id: "a1",
    name: "Account1",
  },
  accounts: [
    acount x,
    account y,
    ...
  ]
}  
// When fetch user(s)
data: {
  user: {
    id: "u1",
    name: "User1"
  },
  users: [
     ...
  ]
}
```

From performance i think its the best to save the json objects from the API directly in the store(s). I will use the JSON objects from the store to fill the update view(s) and overview tables.

From a software engineering point of view i prefer to create ES6 (class) objects. This can have some advantages:

- I can implement a functions like `save()` or `update()` or `fetchUsers()` on for the user and account objects. These functions call e.g. the fetch or update functions (VueX FLUX store).
- I can use inheritance e.g. for the `save()` function etc.
- When i need other functions i can implement them in the object class
- maybe it has other ("model") advantages i dont know yet

In this case i would parse the json data to ES6 class objects and save these objects (or object lists) in my store(s) instead of the json objects.

**Now where i'm looking for:**

- Are there any (ES6?) convensions to follow (can't find them) or whats the best practice for this situation? / Which of the 2 (or maybe other) options is the way to go?
- What impact has creating the objects in terms of performance or resource usage (e.g. for mobile devices?).
- Is the eventual performance or resource impact negligible ? (is there a kind of, maybe best practice limit to the amount of objects?)

I think the sitation and my is questions are clear but let me know when some extra information is required.

Answer (score 2):

Best practice generally recommended for state management stores such as Vuex is

- keep a flat structure, no nested objects
- normalize the entries via object ID

Storing full ES6 classes here might not fit the bill very well here.

For more information here some talks and blogs on the subject:

[Vuex Best Practices (linusborg)](https://slides.com/thorstenlunborg/vuex-best-practices#/)
[Vuex State Normalization](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/make-your-vuex-state-flat-state-normalization-with-vuex/)
[Vuex Best Practices for Complex Objects](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/vuex-best-practices-for-complex-objects/10143)

You mention that you are not very experienced in these frameworks. You may want to ask yourself the questions whether Vuex is the right answer in the first place.

To quote the below reference doc, people tend to overuse such tools and, while learning, using it for storing "everything". General consensus seems to to in the direction of storing data in Vuex only if that's really needed (primary use case is multiple components must access / update the data).

It is not entirely clear from your description if that is the case for your app.

See more info here:

[What Data Should Be Stored in Vuex](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/should-i-store-this-data-in-vuex/)

Comment: Thanks, i understand your answer and read the links. I think in some cases i can use local states and use props instead of Vuex but in that case where should i fetch the data ? in the ("top level") component themselves or a "api helper"? Now i do it allways in the store actions (so nicely maintainable).. - Does it fit better to use ES6 classes in local states (for individual objects/show e.g. for the CRUD actions) or is this also bad practice? I keep using flat structure for overview tables. Last but not least, is it a good practice to do actions like save() in a ES6 class at all?